# What is the correct data structure for a workout journal?

Tags: database, database-design

I have trouble getting my head around the correct data structure for the following application. Although I am sure this is quite standard for people in the field.

I want to create, for learning purposes, a workout journal app. So the idea is to be able to log, each day, a particular workout.

A workout is comprised of exercises. And each exercise has particular attributes.

For example. Workout 1 is a strength session. So I will have e.g. dumbell press, squats, ... which are all sets and reps based. So for workout 1 I need to be able to enter for each exercise the sets, reps and weight used for that particular workout.

Workout 2 is say a running session. This is time based and distance based. So for that workout 2 I need to be able to enter time and distance.

What would be the structure I need to have in my database for such application ?

I guess I should have an "exercise" table. Then this should somehow be a foreign key in the "workout" table. But how can the workout table accommodate varying attributes ? As well as varying number of entries ? (since a workout can be one, three or ten exercises) Also all this should constitute only one record of the "workout" table.

EDIT :
I have tried to come up with a structure. Could someone confirm/infirm this is the correct way to do this ?

So the final result is the one below, for human representation :

Final Result (sport journal)

| Date | Timestamp | Exercise 1 | Sets | Reps | Weight | Exercise 2 | Time | Distance | Exercise 3 | Sets | Reps | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120821 | 10.30 | Bench press | 5 | 10 | 40 | Run | 60 | 400 | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| 120821 | 17.00 | Bench press | 5 | 10 | 40 | NULL | NULL | NULL | Squats | 3 | 5 | 120 |

But I guess this can't really be achieved as such as this is not (I think) possible in a relational database. So I need to have separate tables and the human view shown above will be a join of those various databases. For example, one "record" of the human view can be obtained by a join of various tables based on the date and timestamp i.e. the actual timing of the workout.

If that is correct, then I think a structure like this could work (at least, the ideas are there I think) :

Exercise database (so simply the list of exercises with their type which determines the attributes needed)

| Name | Type |
| --- | --- |
| Bench press | Setsreps |
| Run | Run |
| Squats | Setsreps |

Attributes (the attributes depending on exercise type. Maybe should split furhter to avoid varying number of columns depending on this exercise type i.e. run vs setsreps?)

| Attributes | Attribute1 | Attribute2 | Attribute3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| setsreps | Sets | Reps | Weight |
| Run | Time | Distance | NULL |
| Carry | Weight | Distance | NULL |

Setsreps instances database (so the actual realization of the exercise on a certain day. This table will be huge !)

| Date | Timestamp | Exercise | Sets | Reps | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120821 | 10.30 | Bench press | 5 | 10 | 40 |
| 120821 | 17.00 | Squats | 3 | 5 | 120 |

Run instances database (same as above but for run instances. Since a run instance has different attributes than a setsreps instance. Is this the correct way to do this ?)

| Date | Timestamp | Time | Distance |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 120821 | 10.30 | 60 | 400 |
| 170821 | 17.00 | 120 | 800 |

So then I could have the "human" view by performing a join of the setsreps & run tables on a particular data and timestamp (which together form a primary key)

Is this a correct way of thinking ?

Thanks for the support

Comment: There are many objects and interactions which might make this very involved.  It's a single user system?

Comment: @SteveC at first… yes. For me :)

Answer (score 0):

> A workout is comprised of exercises. And each exercise has particular
> attributes.

One way to do this is to have a Workout table, an Exercise table, and an Attribute table.  The Wikipedia article, [Database normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization), will help you understand how to create a normalized database.

I'm assuming that you're not going to share attributes with exercises.  If you do, this changes a one to many relationship between exercises and attributes to a many-to-many relationship. You would need a junction table to model a many to many relationship.

The Exercise table will have a foreign key for the Workout table.  The Attribute table will have a foreign key for the Exercise table.

Comment: Thanks. Specific question : one record in the workout table will be 3 or 5 or 10 exercises. So I should foresee e.g if maximum 10 exercises can be imagined, a maximum of 10 columns dedicated to exercises entries and leave them NULL if unused ?

Comment: @FenryrMKIII: No.  One row in the workout table will be 3 or 5 or 10 **rows** in the exercise table.  Each row contains one and only one workout, exercise, or attribute.